# C# Lock access to method per request

Tags: c#, .net, locking

I have a method, UserPropertyRepository.Get(), that I only want to call one time per web request.

Currently I store the result of the service in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection, but as the service can take some time to finish, we often experience that the service is called multiple times before the result is stored in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection. How do i lock the access to the service per request?

My code currently look like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Items[FavoriteGameRequestCacheKey] != null)
  return (IDictionary<ID, FavoriteGame>)HttpContext.Current.Items[FavoriteGameRequestCacheKey];

var favoriteGames = UserPropertyRepository.Get(FavoriteGameUserPropertyKey);

HttpContext.Current.Session[FavoriteGameRequestCacheKey] = favoriteGames
```

Comment: Instead of storing the data, store a `Task<T>` that results in the data, or, similarly, a `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: @spender could you give an example of that?

Comment: Sure. I wrote you an answer that fleshes this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By storing a [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can ensure that races to initialize your data do not result in the initialisation code being run more than once.

So:

```
if(myCache[cacheKey] == null)
{
    myCache[cacheKey] = new Lazy<IDictionary<ID, FavoriteGame>>(
        //initialisation only occurs when accessing Value property of Lazy,
        //so this assignment happens very quickly. Caveat, it's still
        //not atomic (i.e. you might get a context change after the null
        //check, but before the assignment.)
        () => UserPropertyRepository.Get(FavoriteGameUserPropertyKey),
        true //thread-safe
    );
}
return myCache[cacheKey].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @spender, it is just what i needed.

Comment: @pwind : Similarly, if your initialisation is asynchronous, you could store an uncompleted `Task<T>` or even a `Lazy<Task<T>>`.

Comment: This looks fine, but isn't. There is still a small chance two threads will observe `myCache[cacheKey] == null` to be true, so you'll end up with 2 `Lazy` objects. Chances will be small, but still...